# How can I perform a symbolic logistic regression using gramEvol package in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, artificial-intelligence

I am interested in determining a binary outcome (complicated vs uncomplicated hospital) in patients undergoing surgery. This what I have until now:

```
ibrary(readxl)
library(gramEvol)
library(ggplot2)
library(parallel)
data <- read_excel("data.xlsx")

X<-data[,c(3:6,162,163,173)] #interested variables of large dataset
y<-data$compl #binary outcome

set.seed(27)
train_idx <- createDataPartition(y, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
X_train <- X[train_idx, ]
X_test <- X[-train_idx, ]
y_train <- y[train_idx]
y_test <- y[-train_idx]

grammarDef <- CreateGrammar(list(
  expr  = grule(op(expr, expr),var),
  op    = grule(`+`, `-`, `*`,`/`), #operators
  var   = grule(X_train$bmi, X_train$pat_age,n), #variables to test
  n     = gvrule(seq(-10,10,by=0.01)) #constants
))


SymRegCostFunc <- function(expr) {
  result <- eval(expr)
  
  if (any(is.nan(result)))
    return(Inf)
  
  return (mean(log(1 + abs(y_train - result))))
}

# run GE
ge<-GrammaticalEvolution(grammarDef, SymRegCostFunc)
ge
```

I was also would like to know how one could implement categorical data in the variables (sex, family history, etc....)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What is your question? (You say "I [would?] also like to know ...", this implies that you have some other question that comes before this ...)  Can we have a [mcve] please?  The easiest way to generate suitable predictor variables from categorical data would be to use `model.matrix()` to generate your `X` matrix ...